# How to create DB Context run time?

Tags: entity-framework-core, dbcontext

In my asp.net core application, each client has their own database schema.
Hence there are many databases. Sometimes the tables and fields will be different.

I have used Entity Framework core as ORM and we are following Generic Repository pattern.
Is there any option to generate DB Context at run time corresponding to each client?

Thanks
Krishnan

Comment: Since the DBContext takes a connection string as a constructor parameter, have you tried just creating multiple DBContext instances, each instantiated with their own connection string? Then you can create multiple SQL users and have each one in a seperate connection string.

Comment: Planning to create multple DBContext with different names. I mean by adding ClientId at the end